# Move reference (rvalue) to function

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I was reading some documentation and saw this:

```
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) &&> : std::true_type {};
```

Quoted from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function

How can you have a rvalue reference to a function?

From what I understand, functions don't have storage lifetimes. Could someone explain this? I understand references and pointers but how can you "move" a function?

I wrote this code and it compiles and runs as it should:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(int num) {
    return num + 1;
}

int main() {

    int (*bar1)(int) = &foo;
    cout << bar1(1) << endl;

    int (&bar2)(int) = foo;
    cout << bar2(2) << endl;

    auto bar3 = std::move(bar2); // ????
    cout << bar3(3) << endl;
    cout << bar2(2) << endl;

    int (&&bar4)(int) = foo; // ????
    cout << bar4(4) << endl;

}
```

Lets just say if you could store functions as bytecode/opcodes in memory, and 'move' that around. Wouldn't the CPU prevent it from running?

EDIT: @NicolBolas corrected my misunderstanding, but here is an answer for my other 'question': [rvalue reference to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146508/)

Comment: Rvalue references don't mean "move".

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html)

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant it as to apply move semantics. Instead of copying the machine instructions, it would 'move' it.

Comment: You *can* have an rvalue reference to a function, but `Ret(Args...) &&` isn't it. It would be spelled `Ret (&&)(Args...)`.

Comment: You can neither 'copy' nor 'move' machine instructions. None of this have anything to do with what's going on in your code. You are simply "moving" a function pointer. Moving a function pointer just copies it (same as for all fundamental types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can you have a rvalue reference to a function?

That's not what that means.

The `&&` at the end of `Ret(Args...) &&` refers to the ability for [a member function to have an rvalue `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17521238/734069). So that specialization works for a function type that has `Ret` as the return value, `Args` as its arguments, and uses an rvalue `this`.

So it's not an "rvalue reference to a function". It's a function that takes an rvalue `this`.

Comment: This doesn't look like the full story to me - a function doesn't take `this` at all, wouldn't it have to be a pointer-to-method declared as `Ret(Class::*)(Args...) &&`?

Comment: Ah, I see what I'm missing - `Ret (Class::*)(Args...) &&` can also be written `using F = Ret(Args...) &&;` `F Class::*`.